# Method with (void)sender as the first line

Tags: objective-c, casting, arguments

What does the `(void)sender;` do in following code? I am not able to understand what the use of that expression is.

```
- (IBAction)signIn:(id)sender {
       (void)sender;    
       [self dismissKeyboardIfNeeded];
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's one way of letting the compiler know that the `sender` parameter is not used in the method.

Comment: IS there any particular reason why we need to tell compiler ?

Comment: You can enable warnings about unused function and method parameters; in some cases, you may not be able to change the method signature and so don't want to be warned about unused parameters.

Comment: I've never seen such a warning.  It's not normally enabled, AFAIK, even though unused local declares are flagged.

Comment: @HotLicks: Check out the gcc warning options, which are also supported by clang, I believe: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html

Comment: why send in a parameter, that is not going to be used?

Comment: @lakesh: Callbacks often taken a pre-determined set of parameters. For example, in Cocoa, UI actions take a `sender` parameter, but you might not actually use the `sender` parameter in your code.